# .htaccess causes Internal Server Error on xampp

Tags: .htaccess, xampp

I have .htaccess file and i write two command like that:

```
ReWriteRule ^member/(.*)$ /oz/photos.php?member=$1

ReWriteRule ^(.*)$ /oz/profile.php?username=$1
```

and this is the fault:

> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable  to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator at postmaster@localhost to
>   inform  them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you
>   performed just  before this error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log.
>
> Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while
>   trying  to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
>
> Apache/2.4.29 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2n PHP/5.6.33 Server at localhost
>   Port 80

Comment: It says **More information about this error may be available in the server error log.** … so look in the server error log!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your rule `ReWriteRule ^(.*)$ /oz/profile.php?username=$1` is looping the request every time (recursion OR redirect Loop). The all selector in rule is redirecting the redirected request too.

try

```
ReWriteRule ^member/(.*)$ /oz/photos.php?member=$1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/oz/.*
ReWriteRule ^(.*)$ /oz/profile.php?username=$1
```

Comment: thanks, the first url work successfully, but the second no.

Comment: the page is object not found

Comment: do you have that URL working? `/oz/profile.php` OR do you have this profile.php in oz directory?

Comment: ok, i do 2 get method in this page and work successfully, but css files don't work why ?

Comment: check the network tab. by F12 developer tool. it will show you what wrong with the URL.

Comment: have you used relative URLs Or absolute URLs in CSS loading?

Comment: like this  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style1.css">

Comment: this won't work ` <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style1.css">` whenever the link url gets changed it adopt the URL in href. example your. URL is http://localhost/abcd then that link become ` <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost/abcd/css/style1.css">` Rather use. ` <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style1.css">`

Comment: it don't work,in main page it work when i put <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style1.css"> but the page the beccome oz/photos/username form htaccess file don't work

Comment: share the view-source of that page, it would be more helpful if you can provide the directory structure.

Answer (score 0):

Go inside your root folder and Delete/Move the.htaccess file from there and bruh! Solved! It's worked for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).